# Scipy's convolve2d increasing the values in array significantly

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I'm working with images, and the maximum values a pixel can have is 255, but on convolving after rotating the image, the value increases drastically, and reaches 1000s, hence giving me a white image. What's the reason behind this?

Here's the code:

```
        h.extend([scipy.misc.imrotate(h[0], 15*i, 'bicubic') for i in range(1, 12)])
        h = np.asarray(h)
        print h.shape
        R = []
        for i in range(0, 12):
            R.append(scipy.signal.convolve2d(self.img,  h[i], mode = 'same'))
        R = np.asarray(R)
        rt = np.zeros(self.img.shape)
        x, y = self.img.shape
        print (x,y)
        for i in range(0, x):
            for j in range(0, y):
                for k in range(0, 12):
                    if k == 0:
                        max_er = R[k][i, j]
                        #print max_er
                    if(R[k][i, j]>max_er):
                        max_er = R[k][i, j]
                rt[i, j] = max_er
```

Comment: To be clear, are you saying the 1000s are in the rt array?

Comment: in the `R` array as well.

Comment: Well you could scale the image back to 256, but the first thing I'd think of is that the convolution kernel is not normalized, that is the integral over it is not 1.

Comment: How do I normalize it?

Comment: Normalize in this meaning is that you find the sum of all elements then divide each element by the sum, so now the sum =1.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Dividing each element by sum would make sum = 1
?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on 2D convolution but I'll explain 1D convolution and hopefully you can see how it relates to 2D convolution. Convolution is defined as the following (for discrete sequences):

```
(f*g)[n] = sum over all i f[i] * g[n-i]
```

`f` and `g` need to have compact support (i.e. not have non-zero values off to infinity). As an example, take f and g to be:

```
f = 1,1,1,1
g = 1,1,1,1
f*g = 1,2,3,4,3,2,1
```

As you can see, the convolution of `f` and `g` results in values larger than are in the inputs of either sequence. Roughly this can be though of as `a+b` and `a*b` can result in values greater than exist in either `a` or `b`. In short, there's no reason to believe that a convolution would be limited to the input values.

2D convolution is defined as:

```
(f*g)[m,n] = sum over all j sum over all i f[i,j] * g[m-i,n-j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the librairy which is named : [astropy](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/). You have lots of functions which let to make convolution etc .. You can process images / data tables etc ...